# Sybase connection not released although should

Tags: c#, connection, sybase

I have build my own connection pool in Sybase as I couldn't figure out how if Sybase had one working for C#.

Works fine. However **impossible to release the connections** (I close and dispose though). Would you know anything about this?

**Stopping the connections:**

```
    protected void StopDbConnections()
    {
        var count = _dbConnectionPool.Count;
        while (_dbConnectionPool.Count != 0)
        {
            var connection = _dbConnectionPool[0];
            CloseDbConnection(connection);
            _dbConnectionPool.Remove(connection);
        }
    }


    private void CloseDbConnection(AseConnection connectionToClose)
    {
        if (connectionToClose != null)
        {
            connectionToClose.Close();
            connectionToClose.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**In case you need, the connection pool definition:**

```
    protected void StartDbConnections(int numberOfConnections = 1)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfConnections; i++)
        {
            AseConnection connection = null;
            if (_dbConnectionPool.Count > i)
            {
                connection = _dbConnectionPool[i];
                if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    StopDbConnection(connection);
                }
            }
            connection = InitializeConnection();
            _dbConnectionPool.Add(connection);
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found how to do this: needed to specify the `ConnectionIdleTimeout` [parameter in the connection string](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20066.0115/html/adonet/Asaconnection_apiref.htm)